# Scroll over for winter bash not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2014

If you click either "Stack Exchange" inbox or achievements on the top bar and then scroll over to another while they are dropped down, the next icon will drop down, *except* winter bash icon.

Not really a huge problem, not causing anyone any issues, just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional, see [New Winterbash menu doesn't open on hover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211697/new-winterbash-menu-doesnt-open-on-hover/211701#211701).

Comment: Fair enough, just feels strange.